# отличие [*dict.keys()] от list(dict.keys())

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли разница между этими выражениями?

`[*dict.keys()]` от `list(dict.keys())`

Comment: а что вы хотите делать дальше, как вы хотите применять полученный результат?

Comment: Далее хочу сделать проверку вхождения элемента в список:
b = [1,2,3,]
a = [*dict.keys()]
if a in b:
.....

Comment: в вашем случае разницы в общем-то нет, возможно отличие в скорости исполнения будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По результату разницы нет. А вот по тому, как оно выглядит внутри, разница есть. Сделаем две функции с этими реализациями:

```
def func1(d):
    return [*d.keys()]

def func2(d):
    return list(d.keys())
```

Посмотрим, что там внутри:

```
import dis

dis.dis(func1)
print()
dis.dis(func2)
```

Вывод:

```
  4           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (keys)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1
              8 RETURN_VALUE

  7           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (d)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              1 (keys)
              6 CALL_METHOD              0
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Как видно в первом варианте вызывается встроенный метод `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`, а во втором ищется и вызывается функция `list`. Подозреваю, что второе должно быть медленнее. Проверим:

```
from timeit import timeit
import seaborn as sns

n = 8
a = []
b = []
for i in range(n):
    r = range(2**i)
    d = dict(zip(r, r))
    a.append(timeit(lambda: func1(d)))
    b.append(timeit(lambda: func2(d)))
    
sns.lineplot(x=range(n), y=a, label='[*d.keys()]');
sns.lineplot(x=range(n), y=b, label='list(d.keys())');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С ростом размера словаря скорость падает, абсолютная разница времени выполнения остаётся примерно та же, но она всё менее заметна на фоне общего времени выполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]